# Android-firebase problem: "cannot resolve symbol 'storage' "

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Writing in Java for Android Studio. I'm trying to add a download from Firebase feature to my app, but despite the dependencies and imports I've added, I get an error saying "cannot resolve symbol 'storage'".

Here's my class where I need the download implementation:

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.OnProgressListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.*;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SearchResultPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    StorageReference storageRef;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_result);

        // Create a storage reference from our app
        storageRef = storage.getReference();
    }
}
```

And here's my dependencies in the gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:+"
    androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:+"


    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'

    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.0'

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code hasn't defined `storage`, and you can't use it until you do.  Maybe you meant to also have this to declare it:

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
```